# Elasticsearch Java API MoreLikeThis not returning documents compared to "_search" rest endpoint

Tags: java, elasticsearch, morelikethis

Intention: 
Elasticsearch Java MoreLikeThis query in Java to do exactly what the below raw `more_like_this` filtered query via the `/_search` rest endpoint is doing.

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "body",
            "description",
            "organisations",
            "locations"
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 2,
          "max_query_terms": 25,
          "ids": [
            "http://xxx/doc/doc"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "datePublished": {
            "gte": "2016-01-01T12:30:00+01:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "title",
    "description",
    "datePublished"
  ]
}
```

And this is my Java implementation for the above:

```
FilteredQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new FilteredQueryBuilder(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("datePublished").gte(("2016-01-01T12:30:00+01:00")));
SearchSourceBuilder query = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource().query(queryBuilder);
return client.prepareMoreLikeThis("index", "type", "http://xxx/doc/doc")
    .setField("title", "description", "body", "organisations","locations")
    .setMinTermFreq(2)
    .maxQueryTerms(25)
    .setSearchSource(query);
```

However, the results far differ from the `more_like_this` rest endpoint was returning.  I am getting matches of about 4/5th of my whole documents in the index.  As if none of the filters are being applied

Targeting ES `v1.4.2` and `v1.6.2`

Any advice please.Thanks

Comment: You have different datePublished filters

Comment: you mean the difference in dates? if so it was a silly typo in my part writing this up for this post.  If its a difference in the Filter mechanism please elaborate, thanks @alpert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desire results with `QueryBuilders.moreLikeThisQuery()`. Inspirations from this post [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/aebl8Dxq6Rs/3dotse9qXaQJ).

```
 FilterBuilder filterBuilder = FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("datePublished")
        .gte("2016-01-01T12:30:00+01:00")
        .includeLower(false).includeUpper(false);

    MoreLikeThisQueryBuilder mltQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.moreLikeThisQuery("title", "description", "body", "organisations","locations")
        .minTermFreq(2)
        .maxQueryTerms(25)
        .ids("http://xxx/doc/doc");

    SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("index");

    searchRequestBuilder.setTypes("type");
    searchRequestBuilder.addFields("title","description","datePublished");
    searchRequestBuilder.setQuery(mltQueryBuilder).setPostFilter(filterBuilder);

    searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet()
```

Notes:

- `QueryBuilders` seems to be the way forward in terms of compatibility with ES v2.0 and beyound
- `@MoreLikeThisRequestBuilder` will be deprecated in ES v1.6 + and removed in 2.0